# How to NOT select only specific elements in a table with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v9s5ezpb/1/

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td><a href="#">test3</a></td>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test5</td>
        <td class="no-alert">test6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', 'table td:not(.no-alert, a)', function()
{
    alert(1);
});
```

I want my code to execute an alert window on each time I click on any of the table TD items, **except** those items that have a specific class or has an anchor tag.

How is that possible?

Comment: *"or is an anchor tag"* - Hint: your third TD element is not an anchor tag, it *contains* an anchor tag.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `<td>` can't be an `<a>` but it can have descendant `<a>` for which you could use `:has()` selector.

```
$(document).on('click', 'table td:not(.no-alert, :has(a))', function()...
```

**EDIT**: Update allowing click on `<td>` with `<a>` but not when `<a>` is target

```
$(document).on('click', 'table td:not(.no-alert)', function(event){
    if(!$(event.target).closest('a').length ){
       // is not click on <a>` tag
    }    
});
```

Used `closest()` to check target in case `<a>` has any children like `<i>` or `<img>` that could potentially be the actual target

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v9s5ezpb/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: It seems like this blocks the whole TD cell. However I want the other parts of the TD to give me a popup message. Only that ``<a>`` tag should be the exception.

Comment: ok...for that we need to use `event.target` ...will update in a minute

Comment: @charlietfl  Interesting , not previously viewed `.closest()` used for checking element against itself . Could also substitute `.is()` for `.closest().length`

Comment: @guest271314 will fail if the actual target is a child like `<i>` or `<img>` because then the `is()` would be whatever that element is, not the parent `<a>`. On the other hand, `closest()` includes both the target and parents

Comment: @guest271314 using `is()` but with `<span>` wrapping text  http://jsfiddle.net/v9s5ezpb/5/  .. doesn't catch it

Comment: @charlietfl Yes , tried it at previous `js` posted; though jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/v9s5ezpb/5/ has `.length` chained to `Boolean` returned by `.is()`

Comment: oops right... but still doesn't work the same using `is()`

Comment: @charlietfl Yes , you are correct . Have to read documentation on `.closest()` , perhaps view source of `.is()` ; used `.is(function() {})` here , though `.closest()` is briefer http://jsfiddle.net/v9s5ezpb/6/ , adjusted selector `$("a, a *")`  http://jsfiddle.net/v9s5ezpb/7/

Comment: @guest271314 easier to read in my mind also. `closest()` is one of my favorite jQuery methods